# Gmail configuration on my Lumia 520

Tags: facebook, gmail

When I try to add my gmail account to Lumia 520 by simply adding a Google account or adding it through Advanced Setup, it gives the error msg -Incorrect password for the imap server. But I am able to successfully add another gmail account to the same phone. Also, I could easily add my Facebook account to the phone and get regular notifications, but am not able to connect to Facebook Chat on my phone.

Comment: It would be much better if you split up this question into two, as the part about Facebook and Gmail are unrelated.

Comment: Do you have 2-step authentication turned on?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to setup synch settings for your device. Try going to this site from your phone and see how things work after giving the proper permission.
https://m.google.com/sync/settings/

Comment: This link does not have any option for Windows phone.

Comment: did for me. Did you browse to it from your WP?

Comment: yes I tried with my WP but it shows options only for Android and IOS.

Comment: I just tried from my 1020, asked for my login information, then gave me an option to manage my devices.

Comment: Doing some looking t sounds like part of the issue is how Google doesn't follow the IMAP standards (why should they, they are Google). Might want to check out some of the hints in this article: 
http://www.wpcentral.com/severe-windows-phone-8-bug-rears-its-head-gmail-users

Comment: I could add Gmail after turning the text notofications off on my Google account but am still not able to add facebook chat to it. Could do it once after deleting the facebook account. But when I went offline on chat, couldn't be online again. I do receive all facebook notifications.